# Why does setup.py run the module __init__.py during installation?

Tags: python, setup.py

I'm installing a package using setup.py:

```
python setup.py install
```

My `__init__.py` in the package I'm installing includes some package level checks, one of it checks whether an attribute is available in `settings.py`. Since it is a redistributable package the `settings.py` is not delivered via the package, but the user has to take care that the settings are correctly set in their project wide settings.py.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django.conf import settings

#check if settings are properly set
if not hasattr(settings, 'PACKAGE_SPECIFIC_SETTING'):
    raise ImproperlyConfigured('Please add the PACKAGE_SPECIFIC_SETTING setting to your settings.py')
```

Now I'm wondering why the call `setup.py install` runs my `__init__.py` (and crashes because it, not very surprisingly, does not find any settings.)

I would have expected that `setup.py` only copies my package and does not run any code. The code should be run whenever another app using my package imports my package into his code.

Edit: Included setup.py as requested

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# vim: ai ts=4 sts=4 et sw=4 coding=utf-8


from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='django-simple-lock',
    version=__import__('lock').__version__,
    license = 'GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL), Version 3',

    requires = ['python (>= 2.5)', 'django (>= 1.3)'],
    provides = ['lock'],

    description='Simple locking implementation as a reusable'
                'Django app.',
    long_description=open('README.rst').read(),

    url='http://github.com/mr-stateradio/django-simple-lock',

    packages=['lock', 'lock.tests'],

    classifiers = [
        'Development Status :: 4 - Beta',
        'Environment :: Web Environment',
        'Framework :: Django',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: GNU Library or Lesser General Public License (LGPL)',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Topic :: Database',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules',
    ],
)
```

Edit: Included traceback:

```
/Users/Me/.virtualenvs/django1_4/bin/python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 9, in <module>
    version=__import__('lock').__version__,
  File "/01_Development/django-simple-lock/lock/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured('Please add the PACKAGE_SPECIFIC_SETTING setting to your settings.py')
```

Comment: When you import your package, `__init__.py` is called, irrespective if you actually "run" anything. So are you importing it anywhere?

Comment: Please include the traceback, and the details of your `setup.py`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `setup.py` is executable python. It is run as a python script to discover your package distribution configuration.

Your `setup.py` runs this code:

```
    version=__import__('lock').__version__,
```

This imports your `lock` package, so the `__init__.py` file in that package is loaded. Remove that call and your setup will succeed. Store the version somewhere else instead.

Note that the trackback even tells you so explicitly:

```
  File "setup.py", line 9, in <module>
    version=__import__('lock').__version__,
```

Best practice is to store the version in the `setup.py` file instead (some examples [here](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/setup.py) and [here](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/setup.py)). The Django project does use the [`__import__` trick](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/setup.py), but it's [`__init__.py` *only* contains the version information](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/__init__.py), nothing else.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I accepted this answer because of the detailed information / further resources provided.

Answer (score 4):

```
version=__import__('lock').__version__
```

You're importing your package in order to get the version, but in order to import it, `__init__.py` is run (because that's what `__init__.py` does in Python packages - it's what's run when the package is imported).

You can just change your `setup.py`'s version to a static string (and remember to update it when you do releases) and everything will work fine.